# What tune is supposed to be used for Esther 2:17?

Tags: torah-reading, megillat-esther

[image: esther 2:17 in a Tikkun, with a notation of "*benigun*" - "with a tune"]

tikkun korim simanim has verse 2:17 in Megillat Esther marked as to be done with a tune (see the picture above). What tune are they referring to?

Other verses that are marked that way:

- The second half of 4:14
- second half of 5:4
- part of 5:8
- first half of 6:1
- many more

Comment: Simanim have a lot of sections marked that way.

Comment: What does it mean? The also have sections that are specifically marked בניגון איכה, but that is clear

Comment: I imagine some traditions have special tunes, not unlike how some traditions have tunes for eg. Az Yashir

Comment: I assume you want an audio recording of a tune that someone uses for this, right?

Comment: I have heard a special tune used for this verse. It is also used for the last verse in Chapter 1, according to most places that I have heard. I can't describe this tune unless I can locate an audio of this, somewhere.

Comment: I find the text interesting because it has the shins differentiated from the sins by having the leftmost arms higher on the sins. Nice and easy.

Comment: @meva. That would be best. A Mention of this custom in a Sefer would also be good.

Answer (score 3):

Webyeshiva.org has a [series of classes from Corey Beinhaker about reading the megilla](http://www.webyeshiva.org/course/purim-preparing-to-read-the-megilla/) (you have to log in to access the files, but registration is free). In the first class, about 29 minutes in, he brings a quote from a footnote in the "Piskei Teshuvot" (I'm not sure which sefer that is). That says that according to the Siddur Yaavitz and the [Elyah Rabba (690:19)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7767&pgnum=437), it means to raise your voice and continue the tune uninterrupted.

Mr Beinhaker explains that *"the voice is raised and the pace is picked up and held at a constant level, both in terms of voice and pace"*

He gives some examples.

---

These verses seem to fall into two categories. The first is "Piskei Ge'ula", verses of redemption. The second are verses or parts that hint to G-d's name.