# Which passages in Megillat Esther are read with a different trope?

Tags: purim, megillat-esther, trop-cantillation

It's common practice to chant certain passages of Megillat Esther with a different trope.  For example, 8:6 is read to the trope of Eichah, as are several other passages; in addition, certain passages are read to the High Holiday nusach.  Is there a complete list somewhere of which passages are read with which variant melodies?

Comment: Similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/80299/759

Comment: Not all communities have this practice. Maybe common in the communities you live in.

Answer (score 3):

[From Rabbi BenYamin Hamburger](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%94%D7%92%D7%99_%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%90%D7%AA_%D7%9E%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%AA_%D7%90%D7%A1%D7%AA%D7%A8)

בפסוקים הבאים קוראים בניגון איכה:
'וכלים מכלים שונים'
'אשר הגלה מירושלים עם הגולה אשר הגלתה עם יכניה מלך יהודה, אשר הגלה נבוכדנצר מלך בבל'
'והמלך והמן' עד 'ומרה' | 'אבל גדול' עד 'לרבים' | 'וכאשר אבדתי אבדתי'
'כי איככה אוכל וראיתי ברעה אשר ימצא את עמי ואיככה אוכל וראיתי באבדן מולדתי'
...
כפי שהובא בספר נוהג כצאן יוסף (תל אביב תשכ"ט, עמ' ר-רא):  "שמעתי מר' יודא חזן ב'פנחס שול' שהיה קורא בקול רם 'המלך' שבפסוק זה בנגון שמנגנים בר"ה וי"כ [=בראש השנה ויום כיפור] המלך שבנשמת [=בפיוט 'נשמת כל חי' בתפילת שחרית]... אולי קיבל כן מרבותיו".

(Ashkenazzi custom)

"Those verses are read at the melody of Eicha:

"beakers of varied design" 1:7

"had been exiled from Jerusalem in the group that was carried into exile along with King Jeconiah of Judah, which had been driven into exile by King Nebuchadnezzar of Babylon" 2:6

"The king and Haman sat down to feast, but the city of Shushan was dumfounded.--
When Mordecai learned all that had happened, Mordecai tore his clothes and put on sackcloth and ashes. He went through the city, crying out loudly and bitterly," 3:15-4:1

"there was great mourning among the Jews, with fasting, weeping, and wailing, and everybody lay in sackcloth and ashes" 4:3

"and if I am to perish, I shall perish" 4:16

"For how can I bear to see the disaster which will befall my people! And how can I bear to see the destruction of my kindred!” 8:6

...

As brought at book *Noheg Ctzon Yossef*, "I've heard from R' Yuda Hazan son of Pinchas Sho'[Shalom?] that he would read the word "King" at this verse with the *Yom Kippur and Rosh Hashana* melody of the word "King" A *Nishmat* Prayer...Maybe he heard from his Rabbies to do so"